# what's the meaning of the "strikethrough" bond in the skeletal formula of this aromatic compound?

Tags: notation

[image]

That's taken from https://doi.org/10.1039/A901537J , which is about direct amination of the depicted nitrobenzene; I'm puzzled about the meaning of that --NHR moiety, specifically why it doesn't connect with a carbon atom, but instead the other end of the "bond" ends inside the benzene ring.

Any hints about what's meant with this notation?